# Would it be possible to blank all graphics card output periodically, even with a proprietary video card driver?

Tags: windows, gpu, driver, screen, framebuffer

I want to write a program to make the entire screen black every N frames, while using a computer otherwise normally. I'm guessing I can do this by digging around enough in an open source video driver like nouveau, but I also want to do it in windows. Given that I cannot modify a proprietary video driver, is there an easier way to do this in a way that would not hang or make too many timing errors as a result of what the CPU is doing? Perhaps involving system interrupts or something?

Comment: That reads like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is actually what I ultimately want to do. I just want to use my Windows or Linux computer normally, while the screen flashes at black at a rate of 45Hz (so if my monitor refresh rate was 90Hz, one black frame every other frame).

Comment: Most of those use proprietary hardware screens/interfacing and only work for stereoscopic 3D use cases (one eye or the other). After some googling I haven't been able to find any examples of people programming for them, much less programming for them without a stereoscopic 3D-oriented API. Surely there must be a way to accomplish my goal in software without having to buy glasses?